# How to refer to an equation in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, cross-reference

I have an equation written in a rst file as:

```
.. math::
   F=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2 & 0\\0 & 0 & \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}
  :label: eq:6
```

It is shown perfectly as:

[image]

Now I want to refer to this equation in the same rst file. I tried somwthing like:

```
I need to refer to this :ref:`Link title < eq:6>`
```

However it did not work. How can I link (e.g. refer) to this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatched indentation for your `math` role, an incorrect role option of `label` instead of [`name`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-option-code-block-name), incorrect ordering of role and its content, and an extra space after the `<` in your link reference.

The following works for me.

```
.. math::
    :name: eq:6

    F=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2 & 0\\0 & 0 & \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}

I need to refer to this :ref:`Link title <eq:6>`
```

There is another reference to [`:math:numref:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#role-math-numref), but I do not think that is what you want.  There is also the use of [`ref`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref) where one can use a label as the target of the `ref`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Worked like a charm!